# Maximum number of blocks that can fit inside a volume.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

Say, I have a solid cuboidal volume of length = x, breadth = y and height = z.
I have a solid cuboidal block of length = a, breadth = b and height = c.

Given, $abc < xyz\ $  and  $\ \frac{xyz}{abc}$ is not an integer.
How to find the maximum number of blocks that can fit inside the volume $xyz$.

My first approach was to truncate $\frac{xyz}{abc}$ to the nearest integer but then I realized that my answer can be bit higher than expected as the volume $abc$ can also represent a volume $a_1b_1c_1$ where $a_1b_1c_1 = abc$

How to approach this problem with the condition that $abc$ is a volume of length = a, breadth = b and height = c.